# How to Re-format this JSON using Lodash / JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, lodash

I need to reformat the following JSON data

```
[
  {
    "name": "Hello",
    "value": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "Hello",
    "value": 11
  },
  {
    "name": "Bye",
    "value": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "Bye",
    "value": 22
  }
]
```

to this:

```
[
  {
     "Hello": 1,
     "Bye": 2
  },
  {
     "Hello": 11,
     "Bye": 22
  },
]
```

There will always be an object with the same "name" field (but a different value in the "value" field) right after. I am stuck and not sure how to solve this. Is it possible to do using Lodash or pure JavaScript?

Comment: Anything is possible. This certainly is.. have you made an attempt to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never before heard of Lodash, but in pure JS this can be solved with two nested loops:

```
function myConvert(long)
{
    var short = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < long.length; i++)
    {
        var key = long[i].name;
        var value = long[i].value;
        var object = null;
        for(var j = 0; j < short.length; j++)
        {
            if(short[j][key] === undefined)
            {
                object = short[j];
                break;
            }
        }
        if(object === null)
        {
            object = {};
            short.push(object);
        }
        object[key] = value;
    }
    return short;
}
```

This is basically:

Iterate over all elements of `long`.
For each of those, iterate over all elements of `short` to find the first element where the current `name` as key is not defined.
Create a new object, if not found.
Add the current `value` to `object` with `name` as key.